# Command to run annotations in Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: android, annotations, intellij-idea

I'm wondering if there is a way to run the configured annotation processors from a command ( build in, ant, external tool) so i can add it to my run configuration before "make".

The reasoning behind this is that I have a large Android project with multiple modules, but only my main module uses AndroidAnnotations. Now i have to rebuild the entire project every time i change something of importance in my main module, which adds to my build time. In IDEA 11, annotation processing was also run on "make", but the build system changed in 12.

Any ideas to trigger annotation processing via another way than "rebuild project" ?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Eclipse compiler in IDEA settings should help until [this bug is fixed](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/471), otherwise annotations should work fine in 12.0.2 release.