# Annotations not processed during rebuild in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, annotations

I am having the exactly opposite problem of this other question ([Command to run annotations in Intellij IDEA 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196732/command-to-run-annotations-in-intellij-idea-12)).

On my configuration, using Android Annotations, every time I rebuild the project it won't process the annotations and report the supposedly generated classes, which end with an '_', do not exist.

But when I run the project, it processes the annotations as expected.

How do I get the 'rebuild' to process annotations?

Comment: IDEA version? If it's reproducible in the latest build, [file a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: I'm using IDEA 12.1.1. I will try to reproduce it on another project.

Comment: My impression is that it is actually processing them but it processes the annotations after it attempts to build everything else and so obviously the build fails on the first try.  On subsequent runs (as long as its not another rebuild) the files are already there and it succeeds.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any workaround?

Comment: Not really. We're now using Android Studio + gradle.